# Trying to Connect to Oracle Database with PHP 7.2

Tags: php, database, oracle, apache

[This is the output from phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U44P5.jpg)

im trying to establish an Database Connection to an Oracle Database. But i get the following issue:

`Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries in C:\xampp\htdocs\TanWLSI\Login.php on line 6`

I have set the php.ini Extension for OCI:

`extension=php_oci8_12c`

`This is the output from phpinfo()
Did i need an ORACLE_HOME Variable ?`

Comment: Do you use Windows or linux?

Comment: I use Windows with xampp

Comment: Have you set the environment variables? `Add this subdirectory to the PATH environment variable. You can update PATH in Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> PATH. In my example I set it to "D:\Oracle\instantclient_12_2".`

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database

Comment: i have done this now :

ORACLE_HOME C:\instantclient_12_2

But get the same erorr message

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4081480 kindly check this URL

Comment: It is saying that you don't have to set the ORACLE_HOME

Comment: try to add C:\instantclient_12_2 in PATH environment and restart xampp

Comment: Path C:\instantclient_12_2

Same issue than before


OCI8 Support enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support disabled
OCI8 Version 2.1.8
Revision $Id: 8a26cf66ca0f9556b6376408c8f71ead69bdbcbf $
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version 0.0.0.0.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version 12.1